# _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib changing content of character pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that accepts a user string and then reverses the order of the words in the string and prints it. My code works for most tries, however, it seg faults on certain occasions, for the same input.

On stepping through I found that the content of character pointers words[0] and words[1] are getting changed to garbage values/Null.

I set a watch point on one of the word[1] and wprd[0] character pointers that are getting corrupted (incorrect address), and can see that the content of these pointers changes at  '_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. I cant figure out how this gets invoked and what's causing the content of the pointers to be overwritten.

I have posted my code below and would like any assistance in figuring out where I am going wrong. I am sorry about the indentation issues.

```
char* reverseWords(char *s) {
    char** words = NULL;
    int word_count = 0;

    /*Create an array of all the words that appear in the string*/
    const char *delim = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(s, delim);
    while(token != NULL){
        word_count++;
        words = realloc(words, word_count * sizeof(char*));
        if(words == NULL){
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        words[word_count - 1] = strdup(token);   
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    /*Traverse the list backwards and check the words*/
    int count = word_count;
    char *return_string = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if(return_string == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int offset = 0;
    while(count > 0){
        memcpy((char*)return_string + offset, words[count - 1], strlen(words[count - 1]));
        free(words[count - 1]);
        offset += strlen(words[count - 1]);
        if(count != 1){
            return_string[offset] = ' ';
            offset++;
        }
        else {
            return_string[offset] = '\0';
        }
        count--;
    }
    printf("%s\n",return_string);
    free(words);
    return return_string;
}

int main(){
    char *string = malloc(1000);
    if(string == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    fgets(string, 1000, stdin);
    string[strlen(string)] = '\0';
    reverseWords(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Among the worries in this code: `free(words[count - 1]); offset += strlen(words[count - 1]);` - Um. you just `free`'d `words[count-1]`. The followup access invokes undefined behavior. And unrelated, `string[strlen(string)] = '\0';` is pointless. `strlen(string)` is precisely where the nullchar terminator had better already be. If you did that with the intent to cull a trailing newline, that isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Hastily added the free before posting code here. But thanks for pointing out the blatant error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the line

```
char *return_string = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

doesn't allocate nearly enough memory to hold the output. For example, if the input string is "Hello world", you would expect `strlen(s)` to be 11. However, `strlen(s)` will actually return 5.

Why? Because `strtok` modifies the input line. Every time you call `strtok`, it finds the first delimiter and replaces it with a NUL character. So after the first `while` loop, the input string looks like this

```
Hello\0world\0
```

and calling `strlen` on that string will return 5.

So, the `result_string` is too small, and one or more `memcpy` will write past the end of the string, resulting in undefined behavior, e.g. a segmentation fault. The reason for the error message about `memmove`: the `memcpy` function internally invokes `memmove` as needed.

---

As @WhozCraig pointed out in the comments, you also need to make sure that you don't access memory after a call to `free`, so you need to swap these two lines

```
free(words[count - 1]);
offset += strlen(words[count - 1]);
```